# Weird JavaGuard error?

Tags: java

I am using JavaGuard to obfuscate one of my `.jar` files and got this error:

> # ERROR - corrupt class file: me/project/main/Main.class java.io.IOException: Incompatible version number for class file
>   format: 52 / 0    at
>   net.sf.javaguard.classfile.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:160)     at
>   net.sf.javaguard.classfile.ClassFile.create(ClassFile.java:116)   at
>   net.sf.javaguard.GuardDB.addClasses(GuardDB.java:415)     at
>   net.sf.javaguard.GuardDB.startObfuscate(GuardDB.java:274)     at
>   net.sf.javaguard.GuardDB.obfuscate(GuardDB.java:243)  at
>   JavaGuard.obfuscate(JavaGuard.java:322)   at
>   JavaGuard.start(JavaGuard.java:179)   at
>   JavaGuard.main(JavaGuard.java:146)

What can I do to fix this? My code compiles fine and the `.jar` export has no errors. I have no problems with my code or `.java` files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are compiling your code using Java 8, then using a version of javaguard that does not understand Java 8 class formats. The **format: 52** in the exception message is the class format version, indicating Java 8. This Wikipedia entry lists the possible values and the corresponding Java versions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

This is hardly surprising - the last javaguard release appears to be a 1.0 beta in 2002. You may need to use another tool

Comment: I found that something is wrong with the .jar itself. I tried using JD-GUI to decompile it and each class displayed the message "//INTERNAL ERROR//"
I removed all errors and warnings in my code, yet when I export the .jar, the classes don't decompile correctly. Is there something wrong with my export method? I am using referenced .jars.

Comment: Maybe jd-gui does not support Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

For the "//INTERNAL ERROR//" thing you can use Luyten decompiler; It'll get your code.

For the "# ERROR - corrupt class file: me/project/main/Main.class java.io.IOException: Incompatible version number for class file format: 52 / 0 at" error, you may want to use a newer version of proguard.

I had this problem (using proguard maven plugin) and got it resolved using the  5.3.2.